# ruby mechanize requires full class name

Tags: ruby, rubygems, mechanize, nameerror

why do you need the full name for mechanize as so:

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby -w

require 'rubygems'
require 'pp'
require 'yaml'
require "mechanize"


yml = YAML.load_file 'login.yml'
user = yml["user"]
pword = yml["pword"]

a = WWW::Mechanize.new { |agent|
  agent.user_agent_alias = 'Mac Safari'
}

a.get('http://google.com/') do |page|
  search_result = page.form_with(:name => 'f') do |search|
    search.q = 'Hello world'
  end.submit

  search_result.links.each do |link|
    puts link.text
  end
end
```

when the mechanize [example](http://mechanize.rubyforge.org/EXAMPLES_rdoc.html) doesn't do that?  This is asked on top of a [previous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8860486/using-mechanize-and-got-the-uninitialized-constant-objectwww-nameerror) question.  Code only worked after reading the previous question on this exact topic and adding the full class(?) name.  I've seem somewhat similar in Java, but only when it's ambiguous.  Here, there's nothing ambigious, there's only the one Mechanize.

Pardon, the actual previous question completely contradicts the above link.  The previous question I was referencing is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3421468/ruby-irb-gives-nameerror-attempting-to-use-mechanize-gem-ubuntu).  To reiterate, two different questions, two different answers.  Maybe the API or idiom changed.

Comment: Why do you `require 'rubygems'` twice and require Net::HTTP and Net::HTTPS? The first is redundant and the last two shouldn't be needed if you are using Mechanize.

Comment: oh, copy/paste as to having rubygems twice.  I'll fix that and remove the net stuff.

Comment: fixed the require stuff, pardon.  Anyhow, same result, the full class is still required on my system.  Question still valid.  thank you though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What version of Mechanize are you using? Try `gem list mechanize`.

Using Ruby 1.8.7-p357, 1.9.2-p290, and 1.9.3-p0 and Mechanize 2.1 I am able to instantiate an instance. For instance:

```
1.8.7 :001 > require 'mechanize'
true
1.8.7 :002 > agent = Mechanize.new
#<Mechanize:0x101baacf0
[...]
```

and:

```
1.9.3p0 :001 > require 'mechanize'
true
1.9.3p0 :002 > agent = Mechanize.new
#<Mechanize:0x102988610
[...]
```

I suspect you are using Mac OS, because you are accessing Ruby at `/usr/bin`. Ruby is not installed by default on Windows or Linux and wouldn't be at that path normally.

Apple's version of Ruby doesn't include Mechanize, so you added it at some point. Because Apple didn't install it it should be benign to update, so do:

```
sudo gem update mechanize
```

Apple does use Ruby for apps on Mac OS, so you have to be aware of that when updating their pre-installed gems.

Comment: well, outside the character limit to give full paste.  However, same result in irb as in ruby for me, though.  Admittedly I'm in the process of upgrading my system, so just use rubygems to bring in Mechanize.

Comment: oh, I'm on Ubuntu but maybe it's a path problem as you suggest.  Maybe that explains the previous question as well.

Comment: !!!!! DEPRECATION NOTICE !!!!!
The WWW constant is deprecated, please switch to the new top-level Mechanize
constant.  WWW will be removed in Mechanize version 2.0

You've referenced the WWW constant from ./bar.rb:14, please
switch the "WWW" to "Mechanize".  Thanks!

Sincerely,

  Pew Pew Pew